# How can we create 1 action group in Azure to trigger a logic app for multiple subscriptions

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

My logic app is sitting in x subscription.
And I need a set of y, z subscriptions to be able to trigger this logic app via action group.

Is there a way I can create a single action group to enable it in budgets of all subscriptions to trigger that logic app?
In Azure portal, this is a limitation, so only way is to create a new resource group and an action group within it for all the subscriptions individually to connect to a particular logic app.

Answer (score 0):

*It is possible to add action group for multiple subscriptions using Azure PowerShell.*

You can try below script to achieve it:

```
$context = Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId "<Provide the subscriptionId in which the action group exists>"
Set-AzContext $context
$actionGroup = Get-AzActionGroup -name "<actiongroupname>" -ResourceGroupName "xxxxxxxx"
$subscription = Get-AzSubscription | select subscriptionId,tenantId | Format-table

foreach($sub in $subscription) {
$context = Get-AzSubscription -subscriptionId $sub -TenantId $tenantID
set-AZContext $context
$setactionGroup = set-AzActionGroup -Name $actionGroup -ResourceGroupName $Resourcegroup -Receiver $email //creates a new action group or modifies the existed one's
write-host "Action added"
}
```

***Output:***

[image]

[image]

***Action triggered in other subscription in Portal:***

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Jahnavi, will try to test it altough this seems to be a limitation from Azure side.

Comment: Try above alternative. It will work. Thank you! @SahilWadehra